# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING in --------------/admin.php on line 26

Tags: php

i uploaded file but it show error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING in ///admin.php on line 26
>   how can fix this error?

line is

```
function index($success){
    include("header.php");
    global $link,$prefix;
    if (isset($success)) {
        openTable();
        echo "<center><font color='#FF0000'>$success</font><center><br>";
        closeTable();
        echo"<br>";
        goto("index.php?file=admin");/  error line
    }
```

Comment: Is `goto()` a function you defined?

Comment: Stackoverflow is turning into a real-time debugger. `goto` is defined as a PHP function, but I haven't seen it used in years in any language...

Comment: @nickhar, it's just a mere `operator`, and it exists since PHP 5.3 indeed, see the [API](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php).

Comment: @Havelock I meant in any programming lang - not php.

Comment: If goto should work as a redirect function then why echo something before?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you're using PHP 5.3, where [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) is an operator and in that line you're calling a custom function `goto()`, which you've defined.

*Solution:* **rename your function**, something like `go_to()` will help.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer PHP manual for `goto` here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

`goto` is used to shift execution to a different point in the same code file and you need to specify an identifier for another location in your code in the same file (refer to the example given in the PHP manual link). If you want to go to another link, use `header()` method instead.

```
header("Location:index.php?file=admin");
```

Manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Well, I do not see any search code here as well as the question is too generic. Are you using a database? Then it depends totally on the schema of the database. As far as retrieving the data in your PHP and displaying it is concerned, you can refer to some tutorials on database connectivity. In case you are using MySQL, you can check out the link here: (http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/mysql_php.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used goto, but I just looked it up in the manual and they never used brackets around the destination. However if you want to redirect to another page, I think you're using the wrong method.